# How to determine rounding precision of intermediate value to avoid loss of precision?

Tags: rounding-error

I have a formula that can be represented as `A * B` where `A = 1 / x` and `B` is a fixed value with a a certain number of significant figures (say *n* decimal places). The result is also rounded, say to *m* decimal places.

To how many significant figures should I round the intermediate value `A` (it may have a non-terminating decimal representation) to avoid losing accuracy in the final result?